# $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))=\lambda^{-1}$ ? Why?

Tags: differential

I'm reading Calculus on Manifold by Spivak and I am beffudled by a particular derivation on page 35 in the proof of the Inverse Function Theorem.

> Let $\lambda$ be the linear transformation $Df(a)$. Then $\lambda$ is non-singular, since $\det f'(a) \ne 0$. Now
>
> $$D(\lambda^{-1} \circ f)(a)$$
> $$=D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a)) \circ Df(a)$$
> $$=\lambda^{-1} \circ Df(a)$$
> $$=I$$

I can see how the first and second lines are equivalent. And it's obvious how the third line is the identity linear transformation. But how does one go from the second to the third line? It seems to imply that $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))=\lambda^{-1}$ which seems very non-obvious to me.

Comment: The derivation of a linear map is constant and equal to the linear map itself.

Comment: @MooS Why not make that an answer? It's about as complete as one can want :)

Comment: @MooS Yes. If you make it an answer, I will accept it. It entirely answers my question. It does make me feel a bit stupid that I did not see this earlier, but that's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem 2-3 (2) from the textbook (see page 20 of *Calculus on Manifolds*) says the following:

> *If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation, then $Df(a) = f$.*

Hence, in this case we have that $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))= \lambda^{-1}$.